# Which jasmine package to use for Node?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

There seem to be at least three NPM packages for running jasmine tests in Node: `jasmine`, `jasmine-core`, and `jasmine-node`.

**jasmine**

> The Jasmine module is a package of helper code for developing Jasmine projects for Node.js.

**jasmine-core**

> Official packaging of Jasmine's core files for use by Node.js projects.

**jasmine-node** (seems to have been deprecated. The last release is from 2014.)

> DOM-less simple JavaScript BDD testing framework for Node

From the descriptions, it sounds like they all do the same thing. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jasmine tests for your Node.JS application just install jasmine-node.

Simply jasmine and jasmine-core the same packages cause it's link to the same github repository, they're for the simple js BDD tests.

Answer (score 0):

- `jasmine-node` is a third-party test runner, deprecated
- `jasmine-core` is a core library, not test runner
- `jasmine` is the default test runner for Node.js

I also recommend to try [humile](https://github.com/megahertz/humile) which is alternative Jasmine test runner for Node.js with additional features.